# Is there a linkedin and Instagram API to fetch my contacts and send messages to them?

Tags: instagram, linkedin-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Is there an API service to fetch my linkedin and Instagram contacts and to send direct messages to them? I need the API to integrate the above mentioned functionality in an application. Are there any restrictions to it?

This is for a mobile application to be developed. I am using react-native and Instagram v1 and linkedin v2 APIs. I was able to get my basic information and create posts in LinkedIn (not Instagram)

I found out that there have been restrictions imposed in v2. I need to know if my requirement is possible.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to send direct messages after the v2 release of LinkedIn APIs and Instagram graph API.

For LinkedIn:
If you have created a LinkedIn app after Jan 2018 you can by default use only v2 API to fetch basic Profile data and share posts. 
The connections of the user can be fetched using the connections API in compliance solutions, but it is not for daily use and has restrictions. 
More details on connections API check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/connections-api?context=linkedin/compliance/context

For Instagram:
It is clear from Instagram graph API docs that it is meant for Instagram business and creator accounts. For non business accounts you can use v1 APIs but only get access to users basic details and follower counts. This too shall be deprecated by early 2020. 
APIs for fetching followers details, commenting on posts etc have been disabled already by December 2018.
Check the changelogs of Instagram v1 APIs.